# Error to add myeclipse 9 plugin subversion

Tags: java, myeclipse

Iam try install new plugin for SVN Repository Exploring, but get next error:

```
No repository found at jar:file/.../plugins.zip
```

Steps

1.-MyEclipse Configuration Center
2.-Tab software
3.-Add site
4.-Add my name and my plugins.zip

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The plugins.zip file is not a valid plugin repository. You don't say which SVN plugin you're trying to install but the Subclipse plugin installation info is here: https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki and the Subversive plugin info is here: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php

You're using a very old release of MyEclipse so you may need an older release of the plugin (i.e. not the current release) that is compatible with eclipse 3.6 (Helios), on which MyEclipse 9 is built.

Comment: Paste my plugins.zin in the next direction: AppData\Local\MyEclipse\MyEclipse9\dropins and worked